# Percentage with condition SQL

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, window, percentage

Let’s say I have a simple table CITY with ID, NAME, POPULATION  columns
I wanna know what is the percentage of cities with > 10000 population.
I can do it with

```
select count(*) / (select count(*) from CITY) * 100
from CITY
where population > 10000
```

or like this

```
select count(case when population > 100000 then 1 else null end) / count(*) * 100
from CITY
```

but I was that it's appropriate to use a window function for that. How?
When I do something like

```
select count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () * 100
from CITY
where population > 100000
```

I get 100 cause over() counts just the remaining rows. So, the question is:
how to implement a widow function for counting percentage with condition?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need window functions.  The simplest method uses `AVG()`:

```
select avg(case when population > 10000 then 100.0 else 0 end) as percentage
from CITY;
```

Window functions are appropriate when you want to retain the original rows in the data set.  When you want to summarize them, then aggregation is what you want -- and in this case, conditional aggregation making use of `case` expressions.